# Deserializing descendent objects

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm communicating with a JSON-based API which I can't change.  It always returns a Response object with a varying Result object inside.  Typically it looks like this:

> { "ver": "2.0", "result": { "code": 0 } }

For certain commands the Result object is 'grown' by adding extra properties:

> { "ver": "2.0", "result": { "code": 0, "hostName": "sample", "hostPort": 5000 } }

I've used Newtonsoft attributes to define the objects as follows:

```
 internal class RpcResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ver")]
        public string Version { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "result")]
        public RpcResponseResult Result
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

internal class RpcResponseResult
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "code")]
        public int Code { get; set; }
    }

internal class RpcExtendedResponseResult: RpcResponseResult
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "hostName")]
        public string HostName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "hostPort")]
        public int HostPort { get; set; }
```

But when the Response object is deserialized:

```
RpcResponse rspResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RpcResponse>(rspString);
```

Its Result property always appears as an RpcResponseResult object, ie. JsonConvert doesn't know to construct it as a RpcExtendedResponseResult object.

Is there some way with Attributes or Converters to reinstate the correct descendent object?  I feel like I'm missing something obvious!

Comment: Are you lookin for something like this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the type of the object is RpcResponseResult.  The deserializer can only deserialize fields that are declared in the type of the field specified.  It can't determine because a class has "hostName" its now an RpcExtendedResponseResult.

If I were doing this, I might make the result a container for all possible fields with default values if needed, and then you can fill another object as needed.

```
internal class RpcResponseResultContainer
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "code")]
    public int Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "hostName")]
    private string mHostName = string.Empty;
    public string HostName 
    { 
       get { return mHostName;} 
       set { mHostName = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "hostPort")]
    private int mHostPort = -1;
    public int HostPort 
    { 
       get { return mHostPort;} 
       set { mHostPort = value;}
    }
```

Then if you **really** wanted to get your object as you want it, you could do something like this in your container class:

```
 public RpcResponseResult GetActualResponseType()
 {
     if(HostPort != -1 && !string.IsNullOrEmtpy(HostName))
     {
         return new RpcExtendedResponseResult() { Code = this.Code, HostName = this.HostName, HostPort = this.HostPort};
     }
     return new RpcResponseResult() { Code = this.Code };
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, credit to Matthew Frontino for providing the only answer which I've accepted.

However I opted not to make a single result container, so here's what I ended up doing.

1. First I started with this page: [How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base)
2. I used the version of JsonCreationConverter provided there by Alain.
3. I added the CanWrite override as suggested there by Dribbel:

   ```
   public override bool CanWrite
   {
       get { return false; }
   }
   ```
4. I also added my own helper function to JsonCreationConverter:

   ```
   protected bool FieldExists(string fieldName, JObject jObject)    {
       return jObject[fieldName] != null;
   }
   ```
5. Then I created my own converter as follows:

   ```
   class RpcResponseResultConverter : JsonCreationConverter<RpcResponseResult>
   {
       protected override RpcResponseResult Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
       {
           // determine extended responses
           if (FieldExists("hostName", jObject) &&
               FieldExists("hostPort", jObject) )
           {
               return new RpcExtendedResponseResult();
           }
           //default
           return new RpcResponseResult();
       }
   }
   ```
6. Then I deserialize the top-level class and supply any converters to be used.  In this case I only supplied one, which was for the nested class in question:

   ```
   RpcResponse rspResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RpcResponse>(
       rspString, 
       new JsonSerializerSettings {
           DateParseHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateParseHandling.None,
           Converters = new List<JsonConverter>( new JsonConverter[] {
                   new RpcResponseResultConverter()
                   })
           });
   ```

Notes:

- Anything not explicitly handled by a converter (such as the top-level class) is deserialized using the default converter built into JsonConvert.
- This only works if you can identify a unique set of fields for every descendent class.